# Как записывать все ошибки в файл

Tags: php, логирование

мне необходимо записать все ошибки в файл, без вывода в браузер

попробовал так, ничего не вышло

```
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
ini_set("error_log", "patch/err.log");
```

после попробовал так

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
ini_set("error_log", "patch/err.log");
```

получил и файл и вывод в браузер

Для каждого php файла нужна своя настройка, поэтому запись в конфигурациях не подходит

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');`

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить callback, в котором будут писаться ошибки и исключения в файл.
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php